How do we convert this table into wikitext format?
The following table is incorrectly formatted.
{
| Left<br>Column  || Middle<br>Column || Right<br>Column | 
-
| (UP, LEFT)      || (UP, )           || Data 2          |
-
| Row header 2    || Data 3           || Data 4          |
}

In the bad formatting, we have the following:


| signifies the left-boundary or right-boundary of a table cell. This is because, in a table cell, the left side looks like a vertical line and the right side looks like a vertical line.

In the bad formatting, - signifies a row-divider or horizontal line. This is because - vaguely resembles a horizontal line.

Curly braces {} signify begin table and end table.



What is the the correct way to write this table in wikitext?

wikitext is a language used for Wikipedia.
wikitext is also known as wiki markup or wikicode.

Perhaps it would be prudent to propose a new site for wikitext on Area 51, but for now, this question is on the webapps forum.


Wiki Code/Text questions are better suited to [so].  See their tag [wikitext] and also  [mediawiki]
